# mdframed and colortbl Connection problem

Tags: mdframed, colortbl

I'm using mdframed for bordered tables. Additionally I'd like to change the bg-colour of some columns using the package `colortbl`. However when I try to load `colortbl` with `\usepackage`, the document refuses to compile moaning about a  runaway argument/forgotten endgroup. When I do not load `colortbl`, the error disappears. Is this a known bug? How can I avoid it then?
The error message in question:

```
Package mdframed Info: mdframed inside float
mdframed uses option nobreak mdframed on input line 2440.
Package mdframed Info: mdframed inside a box 
mdframed uses option nobreak mdframed on input line 2440.
Runaway argument?
{\textbf {Migräne} 
! Paragraph ended before \multicolumn was complete.
```

Comment: The info is only a info and no error ;-). Can you provide an example (My Migräne).

Comment: I've attached a snapshot: ![img](http://s7.directupload.net/images/111221/edbir3px.png). What do you mean by (My Migraine)?

Comment: But you forgot the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get no errors

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[xcolor=table]{mdframed}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{red}}r}
foo
\end{tabular}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code in question is very long so I'm not sure about posting it here (big table). Error doesn't occur when I shorten the table. Has it sth. to do with the table's size?

Comment: @Jan: Can you reduce the code. The size of the table should be independent.

Comment: Thank you Marco. The size was the problem. I don't know where the problem came from but placing it on another page mysteriously solved it. Weird.